# Create decorator with arguments that doesn't modify the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, decorator

**Edit:** The decorator should *do something with* the function at runtime, not modify it.

**I want to be able to add a decorator to the top of functions to execute with arguments at the script start, and print the result (as an example).**

Something similar to the code below, except the code below doesn't work because I don't know of a concise way to pass arguments to it. I don't want to modify the original function, just have it like a "test" section when the function is interpreted.

```
def test_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):  # I'm aware this doesn't work. I'm modeling it after class methods for simplicity sake.
    print("Passed:", args, kwargs,
          "\nResult:", func(*args, **kwargs))

    return func


@test_decorator(70, 20, 10, "last_arg_example:")
def test_example(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4="arg4_example:"):
    print(arg4, arg1 + arg2 + (arg3 if arg3 else 0))
```

I know that the first line of the decorator definition is messed up, but I'm also not clear on how to fix it. All of the things I could find use a "wrapper" of sorts, but I don't want to modify the original, like I said.

If the function requires no arguments, I should also be able to decorate it with just `@test_decorator` above it. Or even if it does require arguments, do nothing with the actual function and print something else entirely.

How would I do this?

**Edit:**
To be more concise, I want the decorator to execute the function that follows it with the argument passed to the decorator and print the output.

```
>>> @decorator(4, 5)
>>> def test1(arg1, arg2):
...    return arg1 + arg2
...
9
>>>
```

Further functionality would be to handle no arguments by just passing no arguments to the function. Here are two cases:

```
>>> @decorator
>>> def test2(arg1=4, arg2=5):
...    return arg1 + arg2
...
9
>>>
```

Here is if the arguments have no defaults:

```
>>> @decorator
>>> def test1(arg1, arg2):
...    return arg1 + arg2
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
TypeError: test1() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
>>>
```

*Keep in mind that I'm aware the interactive interpreter doesn't work like this. I didn't actually try these examples; I typed then out. I wouldn't have been able to test the examples anyways because I don't have a working decorator for them.*

Comment: Now it sounds like you want the decorator to call the function being defined _as_ it's being decorated. with the arguments passed to the decorator...is that correct?

Comment: @martineau Yes, correct. Also without modifying the original, to restate for assurance.

Comment: OK, what should happen to the results of calling the function being decorated in the decorator?

Comment: @martineau Simply printing the result, and maybe log it to a list down the road. This decorator will be defined in a utility file, so I was wondering what the "best" way to make a registry of the results would be without modifying anything but the line above the function definition.

Comment: spikespaz: OK, please see the latest update to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47783782/355230) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@martineau's answer covers how to make a decorator factory that accepts arguments and returns a proper decorator. If you use this pattern, your actual decorator can return the original function unmodified:

```
def test_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        return func
    return decorator
```

The only difference from your original spec is that you will have to invoke the factory explicitly in the no-arg case: `@test_decorator()` instead of just `@test_decorator`.

Now you can do whatever you want in the factory or the decorator, including registering the function call somewhere. For example:

```
call_list = []

def test_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        def make_call():
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        call_list.append(make_call)
        # Decorated function is completely unchanged
        return func
    return decorator

@test_decorator(70, 20, 10, "last_arg_example:")
@test_decorator(60, 10, 20, "middle_arg_example:")
@test_decorator(50, 0, 30, "first_arg_example:")
def test_example(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4="arg4_example:"):
    print(arg4, arg1 + arg2 + (arg3 if arg3 else 0))

for item in call_list:
    item()
```

This registers every decorated function call in `call_list` when the module is first imported, then runs the decorated calls one after the other. It does not modify the actual decorated function(s) in any way. Another nice side effect of that is that you can nest the factory an arbitrary number of times, as shown. The return value of each inner decoration is passed to the outer one, which means that the order in which the function calls are registered is "backwards". The result of the above is:

```
first_arg_example: 80
middle_arg_example: 90
last_arg_example: 100
```

**More Info on Class Decorators**

You can reformat the decorator factory into a class. A decorator (for your purpose) is any callable that accepts a function and returns a function. This means that an instance of a class with a `__call__` method can be a decorator too. The example above can be rewritten as

```
call_list = []

class TestDecorator:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self, func):
        def make_call():
            return func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        call_list.append(make_call)
        # Decorated function is completely unchanged
        return func

@TestDecorator(70, 20, 10, "last_arg_example:")
@TestDecorator(60, 10, 20, "middle_arg_example:")
@TestDecorator(50, 0, 30, "first_arg_example:")
def test_example(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4="arg4_example:"):
    print(arg4, arg1 + arg2 + (arg3 if arg3 else 0))

for item in call_list:
    item()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Another nice feature would be to have it accept no parenthesis. Is that breaking pythonic rules though?

What is the difference between doing it this way and using a class with `__init__` and `__call__`? I ran across that some places too.

Comment: @spikepaz. No major difference, just class instead of function form. A bit easier to read since you don't have to wade through nested namespaces.

Comment: Would it be difficult to transition to class decorator form at this point? If that's more readable and it's an easy conversion I'd like to do that.

Not really sure how, but if I see function form and class form side-by-side I'm sure I'll make the connection.

Comment: So here's the thing about the parens. The outer factory has to decide whether it's a factory that returns a proper decorator or a decorator itself based on the input. It's not actually that hard: `if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):`. But now you can  never decorate a function of one argument to which you pass a callable. Plus using the parens is more consistent since it reminds you that you are setting up a function call, not really decorating a function.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose it would be better to stick with the parenthesis based on that. What about the class form? Should that be done?

Comment: @spikespaz. It's trivial. `__init__` is the outer factory call. It returns a callable decorator, which is the object with the `__call__` method in this case. So have `__init__` stash the arguments in `self` and have `__call__` be the inner decorator that accepts `func`.

Comment: Then in that case it would seem that you can't pass the original function as the reassigned decorator since `__call__` is the new function, right?

Comment: @spikespaz. No, `__call__` is the decorator. It accepts `func`. Its return value is the decorated function. It can return its input unchanged just like the decorator I described in my answer. A class form decorator has all the same bits as the decorator faactory, just arranged so that there is one less level of nesting.

Comment: @spikespaz. I've recast my original example with a class decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? When you pass a decorator function arguments, it must return a "normal" decorator—one that only accepts the original function as its argument. A decorator explicitly passed one or more arguments is effectively a "decorator-factory" function that returns the actual decorator which is then applied to following function definition.

As far as I can tell, your decorator doesn't use any of its *own* arguments—the `70, 20, 10, "last_arg_example:"` values—so in the code below they're just printed and then passed on the original function to get the results from using them which are also printed. So, with all those disclimers out of the way, here's an example illustrating what I've outlined:

```
def test_decorator(*deco_args, **deco_kwargs):

    def decorator(func):
        print('Decorator-factory called: {}({}, {})'.format(
            func.__name__,
            ', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in deco_args),
            ', '.join('{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in deco_kwargs)))

        results = func(*deco_args, **deco_kwargs)
        print("    function returned: {!r}".format(results))

        def wrapped(*args, **kwrds):  # A no-op decoration.
            return func(*args, **kwrds)

        return wrapped

    return decorator

print('Defining decorated test_example() function:')
@test_decorator(70, 20, 10, "last_arg_example:")
def test_example(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4="arg4_example:"):
    print(arg4, arg1 + arg2 + (arg3 if arg3 else 0))

print()
print('Calling decorated test_example() function:')
test_example('arg1', 'arg2', arg3='Not None')
```

Output:

```
Defining decorated test_example() function:
Decorator-factory called: test_example(70, 20, 10, 'last_arg_example:', )
last_arg_example: 100
    function returned: None

Calling decorated test_example() function:
arg4_example: arg1arg2Not None
```

Comment: I think OP wants the outer function call to add the function call to a registry somewhere instead of actually decorating it. Either way, +1 for showing how to pass args.

Comment: @Mad: Thanks again...and in that case I suggest you post your own answer.

Comment: Sure, I guess I will.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In function you are right. I just want to do something with it; not actually change the behavior.

Also, martineau, see the edit for a better description of what I need. That should clarify my question a bit.

Comment: @spikespaz. I've posted another answer addressing what I think your concern is.